# What's this Windows 10 bullseye icon about?

Tags: windows-10-v1511

Ever since the Windows 10 1511 update, I'm seeing a new system tray icon. Unfortunately it pops up, then disappears before I can mouse over and click on it to see what it is.

It resembles a small bullseye or target. I can't recall ever seeing it before and I'm coming up empty on Google. I'm *guessing* it's part of Windows 10, but would like to confirm in case it's malware. I've not installed any new applications, just the Windows 10 update.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's the ["Location sensor in use"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/location-service-privacy) icon. (See under "Where are the location icons […]".)   The actual icon looks like this [image].

It might be triggered by Maps or Weather apps, or possibly by the "Find my PC" feature in recent builds (it's in Settings next to Update/Recovery).

Comment: You are 100% correct. The reason its visible more likely has to do with the fact, Windows 10 version 1511, supports automatically adjusting your timezone for you.  Its just a visible indication that the location service is running.  Of course both features can be disabled.

Comment: Hope you don't mind.  I added the icon to your answer, at first, I could not visualize what the icon would even look like.

Comment: @Ramhound hope you don't mind. I changed the icon to a white one as it looks more visible.

Comment: @ardaozkal - I approved your edit.  Yours is easier to see.

Comment: `automatically adjusting your timezone` could have used that a month ago... didn't it existed!